# How to listen for window.forward() events? (HTML5 history API)

Tags: javascript, html5-history

After pushing URLs with `window.history.pushState`, I can listen when users press the back button on the browser via `window.onpopstate`:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  alert("Going back to: " + document.location);
}
```

But what if the user presses forward on their browser? The above handler doesn't get called.

For example, let's say user starts at A then navigates to B. He presses back to go back to A, which triggers the above `onpopstate` handler, but what if he then presses forward to back to B?

How do I listen to such events?

Comment: That same event should get called. See [MDN's article on the History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Working_with_the_History_API#The_popstate_event).